# How do I keep a generic table for locations

Tags: sql, database-design

This questions is more about trying to find out what others have learnt about storing information in regards to Locations, These need to be generic, so not a collection of tables with specific levels, more of a table capable of handling many levels, and then best way of extracting this data.

Yeah sounds like homework, but I assure you it is not!!

For example, what I hope to achieve is a way of having a location, in this case it will be a box, on a shelf, in a row of shelves, in a room, in a building.

I was thinking it would be using a table that stores its own ParentId, but then my head hurts trying to figure out how to get all the locations back when they might not all be the same depth.

I really hope I am explaining this right....

**Locations**

---

- Building 1

  - Room 1

    - Aisle A

      - Rack 1

        - Box 24
        - Box 82
        - Box 97
      - Rack 2

        - Shelf 1
        - Shelf 2

          - Box 45
          - Box 64
        - Shelf 3
      - Rack 3
      - Rack 4
    - Aisle B
    - Aisle C
  - Room 2

---

How would I write the SQL to Select all of this data out?

What would the SQL look like?

Has anyone ever done something similar?

Comment: I was thinking about having a table that has ID, ParentID, Name, Description, but then, is that limiting the table?

Comment: I recommend looking at Bill Karwin's articles on hierarchies in SQL.

Comment: Thank you reaanb!!